# How to change computer name in Google Drive desktop?

Tags: macos, google-drive

How to change company name here. It's not the same with the name in System preference -> general.

OS: macOS Ventura

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Support answer in the post
[How to change computer name Google Drive uses to sync windows Documents and Pictures folders?](https://support.google.com/drive/thread/18480850/how-to-change-computer-name-google-drive-uses-to-sync-windows-documents-and-pictures-folders?hl=en)

> It's same as the way to change a file or folder name in the web page
> of Google Drive, right-click on the "My Model Computer" to choose
> "Rename" in the menu.

---

[image]